# Ion-Split-Pane doesn't scale to mobile

Tags: ionic-framework, responsive-design, ionic3

I have a mobile app/website (in Ionic 3.25) under construction and wanted to support the desktop web browser experience without wasting all that screen space. I stumbled across Ion-Split-Pane. It seemed perfect from the documentation, allowing me to pop open the sidemenu as a full menu when a large screen was used. I set the code as recommended in the app.html file:

```
<ion-split-pane when="md">
  <ion-menu [content]="content">
    <ion-header>
      <ion-toolbar>
        <ion-title>Menu</ion-title>
      </ion-toolbar>
    </ion-header>
    <ion-content>
        <ion-list>
          <button menuClose ion-item *ngFor="let p of pages" (click)="openPage(p)">
            {{p.title}}
          </button>
        </ion-list>
      </ion-content>
  </ion-menu>
  <!-- Disable swipe-to-go-back because it's poor UX to combine STGB with side menus -->
  <ion-nav [root]="rootPage" #content swipeBackEnabled="false"></ion-nav>
</ion-split-pane>
```

The behavior I'm getting when using Ionic Serve is baffling. When I use a large screen (above somewhere around 922 pixels wide), I get a three pane experience, with a bunch of whitespace containing nothing in the far right. This was surprising, since I thought the app would use the available space:

[image: Full Screen Experience]

When I then shrink below that size, the entire website/app disappears. The elements are still in the html, but nothing is drawn to the screen.

This behavior is so far from the documentation that I must have something wrong, but I'm not certain what. Anyone know how I could get this panel working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After working on this for a while, I discovered my problem. It isn't mentioned explicitly in the documentation, so I'll post the answer here in case anyone else runs into it.

When converting a side-menu project to use Ion-Split-Pane, the content section needs to have the **main** keyword added to the `<ion-nav>` object. #content and [root] are not enough.

The amended code:

```
<ion-split-pane when="md">
  <ion-menu [content]="content">
    <ion-header>
      <ion-toolbar>
        <ion-title>Menu</ion-title>
      </ion-toolbar>
    </ion-header>
    <ion-content>
        <ion-list>
          <button menuClose ion-item *ngFor="let p of pages" (click)="openPage(p)">
            {{p.title}}
          </button>
        </ion-list>
      </ion-content>
  </ion-menu>
  <!-- Disable swipe-to-go-back because it's poor UX to combine STGB with side menus -->
  <ion-nav [root]="rootPage" main #content swipeBackEnabled="false"></ion-nav>
</ion-split-pane>
```

Without that line, the entire application is thrown into the 'menu' pane and simply disappears when going to the mobile view.